Kubernetes- execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server
I am trying to create a bare metal Kubernetes cluster of one master node and three worker nodes. The nodes are Ubuntu VMs running in a VMWare Workstation lab environment. The master node is successfully initiated and it is in a "ready" state, but I am unable to join any worker node. The error message I got is:

execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API
Server

.
master:
    root@master:~# kubectl get nodes
    NAME     STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
    master   Ready    control-plane   38h   v1.29.3


    root@master:~# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36683/kubelet
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39403/kube-proxy
    tcp        0      0 192.168.13.1:2379       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      35077/etcd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      35077/etcd
    tcp        0      0 192.168.13.1:2380       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      35077/etcd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      35077/etcd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      79799/kube-controll
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      35132/kube-schedule
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      63271/systemd-resol
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1355/sshd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34487         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1137/containerd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2748/sshd: master@p
    tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      36683/kubelet
    tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      35116/kube-apiserve
    tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      39403/kube-proxy
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1355/sshd
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      2748/sshd: master@p


    root@master:~# sudo ufw status
    Status: inactive`

worker node
    master@new-worker2:~$ sudo no_proxy=192.168.13.1 kubeadm join 192.168.13.1:6443 --token     8htazp.lf07zanopt299271         --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash    sha256:cdf446379eee25fffa7b5fff5409c05884330d3663e62ae3a8352c3d13040614
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
^[[Berror execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get "https://192.168.13.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


    root@new-worker2:~# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37605         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1120/containerd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      865/systemd-resolve
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1148/sshd
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2053/sshd: master@p
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1148/sshd
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      2053/sshd: master@p

    root@new-worker2:~# sudo ufw status
    Status: inactive

I am able to ping thw master nodes IP address 192.168.13.1
    root@new-worker2:~# ping 192.168.13.1
    PING 192.168.13.1 (192.168.13.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.13.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=26.0 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.13.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=24.3 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.13.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=26.6 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.13.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=22.8 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.13.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=27.1 ms

I tried all the solutions suggested by the StackOverflow posts, like generating a new Token, checking the connectivity, checking the ports and I also reinstalled all the Kubernetes components etc.

A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue. That ufw is inactive doesn't say much. There could still be iptables rules, or an external firewall in between.

Thank you. I allowed all the traffic in the iptables IN and OUT, but I still have the same issue. I am checking if is there any external firewall blocking the traffic.

Moreover, I am able to telnet the master node from the worker node:root@new-worker2:~# telnet 192.168.13.1 6443
Trying 192.168.13.1...
Connected to 192.168.13.1.
